# Shell script output in tabular format

Tags: html, shell

I have an output from my script -

$cat file.txt

Jobname  Date    Time    Status
abc      12/9/11 17:00 Completed

I have used the below code to get the output in tabular format
awk 'BEGIN{print ""} {print "";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "" $i"";print ""} END{print ""}' file.txt > file.html

$cat file.html

[image: file.html output]

And then I am sending this to my mail

(

> echo "From: XXXX@oooo.com "
>   echo "To: bbbb@oooo.com "
>   echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
>   echo "Subject: Test HTML e-mail."
>   echo "Content-Type: text/html"
>   cat file.html
>   ) | sendmail -t

I am getting the output in my mail in this format

[image: Present Table format]

Whereas I am expecting something like -

[image: Expected table format]

Comment: I assume you'd have to add the appropriate CSS rules to get the formatting you want.

Comment: Not sure how i would be able to do that. Can you guide

Answer (score 0):

you should add a border to your table, eg :

```
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```