# Parse the html code and send to the mail using mailx or sendmail in shell script

Tags: html, bash, shell

**I want to send a mail using mailx or sendmail with HTML formatted content and receive the parsed output in the mail .**

I want to send HTML code in an email and receive the parsed output as a response after the email has been sent. I have searched and did not find any solution yet .
How this task can be accomplished ?

I have tried to accomplish this task using mailx. A snippet is given below .
mailx -S "$address" -r "$sender" -s "$subject" -v "$receiver" < $tmpfile

where tmpfile is html file which contents the html tags to display a table .
It sends the html formatted always instead of parsed output to the mail .

Expecting : It should send  mail with HTML formatted tag but output in the mail as parsed html tag .

Comment: I don't understand your qeustion at all. So, you have an HTML file, want to extract some relevant part of it, and send the extracted data  by mail? In the code snippet you posted, I don't see anything which could be described as "parsing", so I find your question highly confusing.

Comment: In addition, please [format the code in your question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Displaying code in proportional font is a bad idea, because we can not see the number of spaces properly.

Comment: though your question is not clear. you might want to use -a "Content-Type: text/html" with mailx command.
 mailx -a "Content-Type: text/html" -S "$address" -r "$sender" -s "$subject" -v "$receiver" < $tmpfile

Comment: Please edit your question and try to explain again, it is not clear what you want to do. Do you mean your mail is arriving as plain text, with visible HTML code and tags, instead of a rendered, styled HTML page?  A quick search for "*mailx HTML email*" turns up plenty of tips, do those help?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message

Comment: Just let me explain .Shell script has some array object . Value of array object should be appended with the table tags of html and  stores in the file .in next step SC should read the file and send it to the mail with MIME Type content/html .I was missing this mime type in the SC file that's why it was not able to send the html parsed output .After adding the html mime type it is sending a html table in good format .I have found solution on stack overflow only .it helped me a lot . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099447/shell-script-output-in-tabular-format

Comment: Now I am facing a different issue . Issue is , In the production the font size and size of rows increased but in the non prod ,output of the mail with table is coming with good format and as expected without any issue .could you please help me out with this issue ? @user1934428

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mailx send html message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message)

Comment: If this question was solved by another question on SO, please close this question as a duplicate.  If you have a new question, please post a new question.